# all listview data insert only one row

Tags: java, android, sql-server, listview

I have a `ListView` with multiple rows. When I insert the entries in the ListView into an sql database, all the entries get inserted into a single row.

I get all the entries from the view with a String builder.

How can I solve this problem?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
//get data form text view

for(int i=0; i<simpleAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    String a = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.al)).getText().toString();
    String b = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.sh)).getText().toString();
    String c = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.acc)).getText().toString();

    simpleAdapter.getItem(i).toString();
    sb.append(a);
    sb.append("\n");
    sb2.append(b);
    sb2.append("\n");
    sb3.append(c);
    sb3.append("\n");

}

String text = sb.toString();
String text2 = sb2.toString();
String text3 = sb3.toString();

//my sql connection insert query
try {
    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
    if (con == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in connection with SQL server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        String query = "INSERT INTO suigen.TransAlmiraShelf (Almira, Shelf, AccessionNo) VALUES('" + String.valueOf(text) + "','" + String.valueOf(text2) + "','" + String.valueOf(text3) + "')";

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(query);
        Toast.makeText(Main13Activity.this, "Your Data Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
catch (Exception ex) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exceptions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Please Refer this link.                  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619923/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-sqlite-android

Comment: how to use this method i cant understand in sql server please help me

Comment: this solution is sqllite

Comment: Are you using JDBC

Comment: Try statement.executeBatch(); Refer the below link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892105/bulk-insert-in-java-using-prepared-statements-batch-update

Comment: yes i am using jdbc driver

Comment: Did you see the above link

Comment: yes but my q is how to get every row data or how to insert every list row data into sql

Comment: @PuneetKhattar I know why. I'm writing an answer...

Comment: @PuneetKhattar do you have 3 list views?

Comment: no i have only 1 list view

Comment: but column is three

Comment: @PuneetKhattar ok, so my answer should work

Comment: @PuneetKhattar what's the id of the ListView?

Comment: listView is the id of the listview

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of Values form the table usng JDBC

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("URL", "USERNAME", 
"PASSWORD");
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from 
table");
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

if (resultSet != null) {
while (resultSet.next()) {
    ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
    for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {

        int type = resultSetMetaData.getColumnType(i);
        if (type == Types.VARCHAR || type == Types.CHAR) {
             System.out.println(resultSet.getString(i));
        } else {
             System.out.println(resultSet.getLong(i));
        }
    }

     System.out.println("-----------");
}
```

}

Comment: did you get the list of values form the table

Comment: yes i am get list of values from the textview and put into  the sql server

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding all the information into the string builders before you insert into the sql database.

You can fix this by getting the information and immediately insert it into the database:

```
ListView listView =  ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView));
try {
    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();//first you do the connection
    if (con == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in connection with SQL server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<simpleAdapter.getCount(); i++) {//then create the information you're going 
            View row = simpleAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            String a = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.al)).getText().toString();
            String b = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sh)).getText().toString();
            String c = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.acc)).getText().toString();


            sb.append(a);
            sb.append("\n");
            sb2.append(b);
            sb2.append("\n");
            sb3.append(c);
            sb3.append("\n");



            String text = sb.toString();
            String text2 = sb2.toString();
            String text3 = sb3.toString();



            String query = "INSERT INTO suigen.TransAlmiraShelf (Almira, Shelf, AccessionNo) VALUES('" + String.valueOf(text) + "','" + String.valueOf(text2) + "','" + String.valueOf(text3) + "')";

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(query);
            Toast.makeText(Main13Activity.this, "Your Data Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exceptions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The reason you got all the data in one row is that you used the string builder to build a string that contains **all** the information from the ListView, and not just a single row in the view. Then you put it all in the database.

The solution is to insert into the database one at a time.

Comment: how to get all row and insert

Comment: @PuneetKhattar ok... hold on

Answer (score 0):

```
how to get row value on every time 

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
                   for(int i=0; i<simpleAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    String a = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.al)).getText().toString();
                    String b = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.sh)).getText().toString();
                    String c = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.acc)).getText().toString();
                    simpleAdapter.getItem(i).toString();
                    sb.append(a);
                    sb.append("\n");
                    sb2.append(b);
                    sb2.append("\n");
                    sb3.append(c);
                    sb3.append("\n");

                    String text = sb.toString();
                    String text2 = sb2.toString();
                    String text3 = sb3.toString();
}}
```